# Function is showing undefined value but in console its showing result

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have two functions one is main function and another one is api calling function in which I am calling Api in this function actually it is showing result in console but when I am calling this function inside main function then its showing `undefined` value.

Below  is my code:

```
async mainFun(){

    this.logger.log("in main function");
    const dat = await this.apiFun();
    this.logger.warn(dat);  // Here its showing undefined
} 

async apiFun = () =>{
    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown';
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
     this.logger.log("In nameFun " + response.data.total);
     return response.data.total;
    }).catch((error) => {
       this.logger.log(error);
    });
}
```

Someone let me know why its showing `undefined` value.

Comment: 1) You didn't `return` the promise from `axios.get(...).then(...)`. 2) There is no point in using `then` in an async function in the first place, just use `const response = await axios.get(url)` and use `try`/`catch` for the error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async mainFun(){

    this.logger.log("in main function");
    const dat = await this.apiFun();
    this.logger.warn(dat);  // Here its showing undefined
} 

async apiFun = () =>{
    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown';
    const request = await axios.get(url);
    return request.data.total;
}
```

Comment: Can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406397/how-to-save-api-response-in-mongodb-in-nestjs I have  posted new qns