# How to save api response in MongoDB in NestJs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am using NestJs as a backend service where I am hitting some third party API and want to save response  in MongoDB. I am unable  to get how can I save data in MongoDB as I have DTO class for the data I want to save.

Below is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UserModule,
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/status')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**user.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { StatusSchema } from './schemas/status.schema';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
  imports:[HttpModule,
           ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
           MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Status', schema: StatusSchema }])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**status.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document } from "mongoose";

export type StatusDocument = Status & Document;

@Schema()
export class Status{
  @Prop()
  total:String;
}

export const StatusSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Status);
```

**status.dto.ts**

```
export class StatusDto{
  total:string;
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(private httpService:HttpService,
    private schedulerRegistry:SchedulerRegistry,
    @InjectModel('Status') private readonly statusModel:Model<Status>){}

    private readonly logger = new Logger(UserService.name);

    async dynamicJob(){

    this.logger.log("in main function");
    const dat = await this.nameFun();
    this.logger.warn(dat);
    
    //Here I want to save the dat inside MongoDB
}

nameFun = async () =>{
    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown';
    const result = await axios.get(url);
    this.logger.log("In nameFun " + result.data.total);
    return result.data.total;
}
}
```

How can I add data inside MongoDB at specified place in above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with [json placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2) data that I can test with since I don't know what your response looks like. I'm just passing in the text from the `title` field of the response into the `total` field of your `Status` schema.

Your 2 functions of `UserService` would look like this.

```
  async dynamicJob() : Promise<Status> {
    this.logger.log('in main function');
    const dat = await this.nameFun();
    this.logger.warn(dat);
    const dto = { total: dat }; // creating dto in the form of your schema
    this.logger.log(dto);

    return await this.statusModel.create(dto); // saves and returns saved object
  }

 
  nameFun = async () => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2';
    const result = await axios.get(url);

// you'll need to change this back to correct parsing of your actual response

    this.logger.log('In nameFun ' + result.data.title);
    return result.data.title;
  };
```

Then the corresponding function in your `UserController` would look something like this, which whatever endpoint you want to use. Here I'm just using `from-api`.

```
  @Get('from-api')
  async getFromApi() : Promise<Status> {
    return this.userService.dynamicJob();
  }
```

Get request from this endpoint

```
http://localhost:3000/user/from-api/
```

returns the newly created document in Mongo

```
{
  "total": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
  "_id": "622a1a6e990efa55c984dc4b",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: That's working absolutely perfect thanks for an example.